# Plugin option default value

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

Hi I am making plugin default option sets.I put my code like this.Basically I want to give an image path in plugin folder.I did this .

```
function add_scroll_default() {
$tmp = get_option('scroll_options');
if((!is_array($tmp))) {
    $arr = array("top_image"=>"echo'plugins_url( '/image/top.png', __FILE__ )'");
    update_option('scroll_options', $arr);
}
```

}

Upon inspection on database I found that the value stored

```
echo'plugins_url( '/image/top.png', __FILE__ )'
```

But I want to put the image url?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are two errors in your code.

1. `"echo'plugins_url( '/image/top.png', __FILE__ )'"` is not executed, it is just a string that happens to look like PHP code.
   What you really want is:

   ```
   $arr = array( "top_image"=> plugins_url( '/image/top.png', __FILE__ ) );
   ```
2. Do not store default options in the database. Use the second parameter for `get_option( $option, $default );` instead.

   So whenever you fetch the option, provide the default values as second argument:

   ```
   $option = get_option( 
       'scroll_options', 
       array( 
           "top_image"=> plugins_url( '/image/top.png', __FILE__ ) 
       ) 
   );
   ```

   The reason is that you cannot rely on the stored values anyway. They might be deleted already, so you have to provide the default values *always*.

Comment: I don't think you want the leading slash here either: `plugins_url( '/image/top.png', __FILE__ )` - try `plugins_url( 'image/top.png', __FILE__ )` instead

Comment: @TomC Doesn’t matter, WordPress strips the left `/` from the path.

Comment: Thank you @toscho .PLease help a bit more.I followed your method to fetch option .But it output only Array.Though I found other way using php empty to check for input